# JQUERY $j(this) in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I am using `$j(this)` in my jquery change function. But the `$j(this)` locate the windows, instead of the changing function.

Jquery:

```
$j('#id').on("change", function () {
    var $this = $j(this);
    console.log($this);
});
```

what i get is,

```
[Window]
```

But its wrong. It should console #id's functions. why this error occurring. Is `$j(this)` correct or not? Please help me.. I am totally stuck at this.

Comment: have you tried to change the handler from change to click? maybe ther are some other javascript events which trigger the change event ...

Comment: Thanks@roman204.  i cant use click event.. caz its a slider

Comment: i mean only for debugging

Answer (score 1):

You should use only "this" inside the on event that refers to the element.